# Install the pdo_mysql extension and GD library without access to php.ini

Tags: php, mysql

I recently started hosting my own website thanks to the OVH "personal formula" and found some web-based app that I would like to install on my server. It requires the **pdo_mysql** extension and **GD library** to run. I read that I needed access to the php.ini file to download them.

However, I don't have access to the php.ini file. Is there another way to install both of these extensions ? (Maybe editing the htaccess file...?)

I'm using windows, My current PHP version is : 5.6.17, 
I use a MYSQL  v.5.5 database

Thanks

Comment: what is your os?(windwos,linux,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally need access to `php.ini` to enable or disable modules.

It really would surprise me if your shared hosting provider didn't already have pdo_mysql and GD enabled though. Have you checked the modules aren't already available.

Comment: Hi, using the print_r(get_loaded_extensions()); command, I saw both gd and pdo_mysql were loaded already. I guess it's not the cause of my problems, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Linux users

Run the following command to install GD:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

Restart your Apache web server.

And in Windows you can use

[dl function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php)

```
bool dl ( string $library )
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I was using Windows, thanks though.